# Extend Behavior of models.Model

Tags: django

In django, I am trying to extend the behavior of the models.Model class.

I want to execute code as the model inits, as well as using the default init.

Here is the code I so far which *looks* like what im wanting to do but the behavior is incorrect.

```
class DirtyModel(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DirtyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("extended")

class Foo(DirtyModel):
    bar = models.TextField()
```

This code tries to make a model called DirtyModel, which I understand why, but I don't suppose I know how to extend the Model class otherwise.

How should I go about creating a custom models.Model class to use in my models?

Comment: What is not working with it? What are you doing, and how is this different from what you expect?

Comment: Because it's extending models.Model, django tries to create a table called DirtyModel. Not a huge issue but it makes me think im doing something wrong. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: This is the expected behavior, since you did not specify `DirtyModel` as an `abstract = True` model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How should I go about creating a custom models.Model class to use in my models?

Based on your comments, you likely want to create an *abstract* superclass:

```
class DirtyModel(models.Model):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DirtyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        print("extended")

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

By not setting `abstract = True`, Django will create a `DirtyModel` as well as a `Foo` model here, that has an (implicit) `OneToOneField` to `DirtyModel`.

If you make it abstract, you basically say that one can not construct a `DirtyModel` itself, but only some non-abstract subclasses.

Comment: This was just what i needed, an Abstract Base Class. I'm not very familiar with the terminology, or even if this was possible. Thank you so much.